# Oncreateview is not calling when i am slideing my view?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, slideshow

Hi I am working on sliding fragments when user tap on button are draw the view. By using this library [SlidingMenu library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu). This library is working perfectly.But I am facing a problem in Fragment class when I am sliding a view in my fragmentactivity in fragment class there is no methods are calling What I am trying here is my code :

FragmentActivity: this activity extends SlidingFragmentActivity(This activity is in side abvoe mentioned library project)
       @Override
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
    View view1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.activity_main, null);
    View view2 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.menu_frame, null);
    View view3 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.menu_frame_two, null);
    getSlidingMenu().setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
    getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);   
    getSlidingMenu().setMenu(view2);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.menu_frame, new Fragment1()).commit();
    getSlidingMenu().setSecondaryMenu(view3);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.menu_frame_two, new Fragment2()).commit();
    setContentView(view1);
}
```

Fragment1.java this activity extends Fragment

```
   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("oncreate view");
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment_layout, container, false);

            return v;
            }

    @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    System.out.println("on activity created");
      }

    @Override
public void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    System.out.println("onResume");
     }

    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println("oncreate");
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttach(activity);
    System.out.println("onAttach");
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    System.out.println("on save instance state");
}

@Override
public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);
    System.out.println("onHiddenChanged");
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    System.out.println("onStart");
}



@Override
public void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    System.out.println("onPause");
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    System.out.println("onStop");
}

@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println("onViewstaterestored");
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println("onViewCreated");
}
```

When I am slide a view left are right side the above methods are not calling. But when I am click on menu button oncreateview is calling.

Inside on click I am calling getSlidingMenu().showMenu(); this method.

But i want to call any method when I slide on view. What was the problem in my code?
 why any method is not calling inside of fragment when sliding?

Any one please help me..Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Refer this tutorial. I think it's helpful for you.

[Implementing Horizontal View Swiping Using ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter in Android](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/implementing-horizontal-view-swiping-using-viewpager-and-fragmentpageradapter-in-android/)